# Proof that $\{n\}$ is a Cauchy Sequence. Where is the fallacy?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences, fake-proofs

We need to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb R$ such that $n,m > N \implies |n-m|<\varepsilon$.

$|n-m|<n+m$. So, if we make $n+m< \varepsilon$, the result will follow. This will happen if both $n<\varepsilon/2$ and $m<\varepsilon/2$.

We see that $n>-\varepsilon/2$ and $m>-\varepsilon/2$. So, let $N=-\varepsilon/2$. Then 
$$n,m > N \implies |n-m|<n+m<\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2<\varepsilon$$

I know that $\{n\}$ diverges but the steps of the proof seem logical.

Where is the fallacy?

Comment: The fake-proof tag hints that you want to ask (or say) something about the purported "proof", but it isn't clear where you want to go with this.

Comment: @hardmath edited. To me the steps of my proof seem logical even though I know it is wrong.

Comment: Take $\epsilon = 2$, so $N = -1$. Your inequality fails as soon as $n$ or $m$ exceeds $3$.

Comment: How do you go from $n > -\epsilon/2$ to $n < \epsilon/2$?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Multiply by $-1$, switch the sign.

Comment: That gives $-n < \epsilon/2$, not $n < \epsilon/2$.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez You have an error. It should be $-n>\varepsilon/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your proof is the assumption $n<\varepsilon/2$ (and similarly for $m$). This condition cannot be satisfied for large $n$, so you cannot deduce $|n-m|<\epsilon$ for all large $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $\epsilon=1/2$. Then for any $N$, just let $n=N+1$ and $m=N+2$ so $|m-n|=1\geq 1/2$.

Also note that $n$ doesn't converge so it can't be Cauchy.

Comment: A Cauchy sequence doesn't have to be convergent

Comment: @theportakal in $\Bbb{R}$ they do

Comment: @ZacharySelk I edited my question. I am looking for the fallacy in my proof. Can you please edit your answer?

Answer (score 2):

$\{n\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence. To see this, suppose we are given $\epsilon=1$. We are asked to find an $N$ such that $m,n>N\implies |n-m|<1$. Suppose that we claim to have found such an $N$. Then, note that $N+1,N+2>N$, but $|(N+2)-(N+1)|=1\not<1$. Therefore, the sequence is not Cauchy.

Alternatively, you could use the fact that Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ converge, but $\{n\}$ diverges to infinity.

Comment: I edited my question. I am looking for the fallacy in my proof. Can you please edit your answer?

Answer (score 2):

> For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n,m>N$ implies $|n-m|<\varepsilon$

This is indeed the correct definition of the sequence being Cauchy. But you have not clear that it should be spelled out, more precisely,

> For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that, ***for all*** integers $n$ and $m$, if $n,m>N$ then $|n-m|<\varepsilon$

I emphasized the key words ***for all***.

Now choose $\varepsilon=1/2$ and suppose $n,m>N$, where $N$ is any positive integer. If $n=\lfloor N\rfloor+3$ and $m=\lfloor N\rfloor+1$, we have $|n-m|=2>1/2$.

Thus the condition “if $n,m>N$ then $|n-m|<\varepsilon$” ***doesn't hold*** for ***every*** choice of $n$ and $m$ larger than $N$.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that
$n$ is large and
$\epsilon$ is small.